# Как закрепить getUpdates что бы отправляло последнее сообщения для бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

хотел бы узнать как сделать что бы бот всегда получал последнее сообщения которое было ему отправлено. Я знаю что это можно сделать по [ссылке](https://api.telegram.org/botAPI_TOKEN/getUpdates?offset=-1).

Но как это сделать в самой программе?

```
import telebot  




def listener(message):
    for m in message:
        if m.commands=='/work':
            print("yes")

        elif m.commands=='/start':
            print("no")



if __name__ == '__main__':


    bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
    bot.set_update_listener(listener)


    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Напишите Ваш код, так как не понятно, какой именно модуль Вы используете.

Comment: @Viktor Ilyenko Добавил код. Я пока что сделал что бы оно отвечало на все сообщения которые пишешь одной фразой. Но мне хотелось бы что бы оно отвечало на разные команды разные фразы

Comment: Уточните еще, какой именно модуль используется, заменив первую строчку кода на примерно такую: `import telebot #pyTelegramBotAPI`. Не по вопросу, а в качестве рекомендации по архитектуре программы:  используйте декораторы с хендлерами (`@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])`), почитайте о простом боте тут https://habr.com/ru/post/448310/

Comment: @ Viktor Ilyenko Я пробовал использовать декораторы, но оно не роботает

Comment: Проблема с декораторами, скорее всего, связана с путаницей, которая есть в туториалах: встречались инструкции, в которых указан один модуль, а хендлеры указаны для другого. Но это уже оффтоп и касается другого вопроса, извините.